# MongoDB shell version error (Server has startup warnings)

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I installed **MongoDB** under Ubuntu server and when inter to MongoDB shell i got this error and warnings.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten] 
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
Sun Oct 27 09:58:39.360 [initandlisten]
```

how I hide this warnings 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to suppress **only** that warning, but you can always start your `mongod` instance with the `--quiet` flag.

> **`--quiet`** Runs the mongod instance in a quiet mode that attempts to limit the amount of output. This option suppresses:
>
> - output from database commands, including drop, dropIndexes,
> - diagLogging, validate, and clean. replication activity. connection
> - accepted events. connection closed events.

> Reference - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--quiet

So when you use this flag, you are actually disabling quite a lot of useful information. As you can see from the content of the warning, using the 32bit version will seriously limit the amount of data you will be able to store. I think you should consider upgrading to the 64bit version.